# chessfss: Switching between notation styles

Tags: chess, chessfss

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\textsymfigsymbol{R}a1 versus Ra1

\end{document}
```

Does the [`xskak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak) package have an option for globally switching between figure notation and algebraic notation in a document?

If the package doesn't have such an option, I would like to have a command  that does this (not necessarily--but preferbably--globally) in a document.

Can anyone help me create such a command in case the package option doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\textsymfigsymbol` is not an `xskak` command but from `chessfss`, the underlaying package used to typeset chess symbols. Its output can be changed with the switches `\usetextfig` and `\usesymfig`. The switch also affect games set with `\mainline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}
\usetextfig
\newchessgame

\mainline{1. Nf3}

\usesymfig
\newchessgame

\mainline{1. Nf3}

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}a1 versus 
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}a1

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike! (Spot on, as always.) I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: Well I should know the answer. I have written the package.

Comment: I know. `:-)` Btw. according to p. 20 of the `chessboard` manual you have only a English and a German version of the names of the different chess pieces. The translation in Danish is "Konge" (King), "Dronning" (Queen), "Løber" (Bishop), "Springer" (Knight) and "Bonde" (Pawn).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I never find that helps with questions about my packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It at least means that I know that it should be in the documentation ;-).