# Chess notation: figure or symbol

Tags: conditionals, xskak

This is somewhat a follow-up question to [xskak: Switching between notation styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403080/xskak-switching-between-notation-styles).

I would like to create a command for a pawn move that either gives the name of the file in which the pawn is placed or gives the pawn symbol, depending on whether I have invoked the command `\usetextfig` or `\usesymfig` in the document.

I hope the following explains what I would like:

```
\newcommand*\bonde[1]{\if\usetextfig#1\else\figsymbol{P}}
```

and then use

```
\bonde{e}
```

to indicate a pawn in the e-file, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me create such a command?

I've tried looking at [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) but couldn't figure out if there was anything useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit odd requirement, but it would work like this (the symbol for a pawn is a small p not `P`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessfss}
\makeatletter
\def\testchessfiglanguage{\cfss@textfiglanguage}
\newcommand*\bonde[1]{\ifx\cfss@figlanguage\testchessfiglanguage #1\else\figsymbol{p}\fi}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
 \bonde{e} \usetextfig \bonde{e}
\end{document}
```

[image]