# Chess: Problem with notation style

Tags: grouping, chess, chessfss

This is a follow-up question to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404285/chess-notation-problem-with-pawn-notation).

Using Ulrike's code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404309/15874),

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{expl3}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn \c_svend_figlanguages_clist {@LSB , @LSBblack}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:NnTF {NxTF}

\newcommand*\bonde[1]
 {
 \clist_if_in:NxTF \c_svend_figlanguages_clist { \cfss@figlanguage }
   { \textsymfigsymbol {p} } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\usesymfig

\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\cfss@king@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKingOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@queen@@LSBblack {\raisebox{-0.37ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackQueenOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@rook@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.26ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackRookOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@bishop@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackBishopOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@knight@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.30ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKnightOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@pawn@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackPawnOnWhite}}

\newcommand\usesymfigblack{%
 \def\cfss@figlanguage{@LSBblack}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\usesymfigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e}

\footnotesize

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\usesymfigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e}

\end{document}
```

I would like the `\usetextfig` switch to "overrule" `\usesymfigblack` when they are both used. By this I mean that if I use `\usetextfig` in the preamble and

```
\usesymfigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e}
```

somewhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, then the output should be a `Q` and an `e`. The reason for this is that I use `\usesymfigblack` multiple times in my document to indicate black pieces via figurines but I would like to globally switch between [algebraic notation and figurine algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_notation).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect that you are on a one man mission to get Ulrike above egreg in the rep tables

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hehe. That is indeed my main goal. `:-)` ... and then to get some help regarding (my own style of?) chess notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\clist_const:Nn \c_svend_figlanguages_clist {@LSB , @LSBblack}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:NnTF {NxTF}

\newcommand*\bonde[1]
 {
 \clist_if_in:NxTF \c_svend_figlanguages_clist { \cfss@figlanguage }
   { \textsymfigsymbol {p} } { #1 }
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother


\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\cfss@king@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKingOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@queen@@LSBblack {\raisebox{-0.37ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackQueenOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@rook@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.26ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackRookOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@bishop@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackBishopOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@knight@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.30ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKnightOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@pawn@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackPawnOnWhite}}

\newcommand\svendusefigurine{%
\def\svend@blacklanguage{@LSBblack}
\def\svend@whitelanguage{@LSB}}

\newcommand\svendusealgebraic{%
  \def\svend@blacklanguage{english}% change if needed
  \def\svend@whitelanguage{english}%
  }

\newcommand\svendusefigblack{%
 \def\cfss@figlanguage{\svend@blacklanguage}}
\newcommand\svendusefigwhite{%
 \def\cfss@figlanguage{\svend@whitelanguage}}

\newcommand\svendfigblack[1]{%
 \csname cfss@\csname cfss@input@#1@english\endcsname @\svend@blacklanguage\endcsname}

\newcommand\svendfigwhite[1]{%
 \csname cfss@\csname cfss@input@#1@english\endcsname @\svend@whitelanguage\endcsname}


\makeatother

\svendusealgebraic

\begin{document}

\svendusealgebraic
\svendusefigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\svendusefigwhite
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\svendfigwhite{Q}, \svendfigblack{Q}

\svendusefigurine
\svendusefigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\svendusefigwhite
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}, \bonde{e} --
\svendfigwhite{Q}, \svendfigblack{Q}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm! Can I somehow use `\bonde{}` as an argument to `\svendfigwhite{}`/`\svendfigblack{}`, e.g., `\svendfigwhite{\bonde{}}`? (That doesn't work for me at the moment.)

Comment: Perhaps,but imho it would be easier to extend the input so that `\svenfigwhite{a}`, `\svenfigwhite{b}` etc works.

Comment: Okay, but if possible I would really like to use `\svendfigwhite{\bonde{}}` since I would have to change a lot in various documents if I should use, say, `\svenfigwhite{b}`.