# How to type a chess move that disguishes the black move and the white move?

Tags: chess, chessboard

I was reading this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458072/how-to-type-a-specific-chess-move/458076).

And I couldn't really find the answer.

Basically, how can I type a move of BLACK ROCK to `c8` and for a WHITE ROCK to `c8`?

Something like `\wmove{Ra8}` and `\bmove{Ra8}` produces the SAME symbol (a white rock).

What are the synatex for King Queen Rock Bishop Knight and Pawns for both black and white pieces?

Comment: there aren't many fonts with black figurines, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403758/2388

Comment: hmmmm. My point here is not really with the fonts. As we can setup the game (board), there are black pieces as well as white pieces (the symbols are there, so to speak). So all I want to do, the without setting up the game, being able to present some moves with those figures (fonts)...